# Create a link based on table date on another website

Tags: php

I am trying to think about how I would go about creating a link to something based on a data in another table on another website.

I have the following table on the other website:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqvVD.jpg

so basically columns: Order #, Status, customer P-O

What I am trying to do is create a url based on "customer PO" that links to the Order #. So it would find the customer PO, then check the value on the same row of Order #, and then once I have that value I can create the URL using that order #.

I've never done anything that takes a value from another website so I guess that is what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other web page doesn't have an API that you can use to retrieve that data in a more usable format, you will have to use a technique known as scraping. you would likely use curl or wget to fetch the web page and then parse the resulting html page to pull the data you need out of it. an xml library would be able to assist in parsing, but you may be able to get away with a shortcut by searching the string for a common beginning and ending string.

so for example, if there is only one html table on the page, you can search for

```
<table>
```

and the matching

```
</table>
```

Then parsing the tr and td tags is a little more manageable than dealing with the entire page. In the end it just depends on what this is being used for and how robust it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks I started looking into scraping  and I think I can use your idea of the shortcut already. I am trying to figure it out based on a github tutorial I just found of someone showing how to scrape using php. query('//a href="OrdDetList'); Does not seem to work to find the url starting with that yet. Anyways thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: To get the content in PHP, use $site =  file_get_contents('http://theothersite.com');